# Почему я не могу удалять символ '\', используя strip()?

Tags: python

Код не запускается

```
import os

for current_dir, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\main'):  
    print(current_dir.strip('C:\'))
```

Comment: Потому что \ в строковых литералах это специальный символ, и если вы не имеете в виду ничего специального и хотите просто вписать этот символ как есть, то вам нужно его экранировать \\

Comment: У вас выходит ошибка в коде, потому что `\'` воспринимается как заэкранированный символ кавычки, а не как закрывающая кавычка. Экранируйте бэкслэши. А про конкретную ошибку нужно было написать в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно заменить \ на \\.

```
import os

for current_dir, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\main'):  
    print(current_dir.strip('C:\\'))
```

Python воспринимает \ как символ экранирования. Примеры: \n, \', \" и \t.
\\ является экранированнием символа \. Так что всегда когда в тексте нужно написать \ его надо заменять на \.
Также есть вариант с raw строками - r'C:\'. Но в таком случае если в тексте используется \n, \', \" и так далее они работать не будут. Так как в raw строках экранирование не работает.